# JavaScript Calculator problems

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am messing a bit with JavaScript and decided to make a calculator. For now all I want it to do is to input what button was pressed into Answer box, but I can't make it to work, I think something is wrong with my functions, but I can't figure out what, please help...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    var one = function() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "1"
    }

    function two() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "2"
    }

    function three() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "3"
    }

    function four() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "4"
    }

    function five() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "5"
    }

    function six() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "6"
    }

    function seven() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "7"
    }

    function eight() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "8"
    }

    function nine() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "9"
    }

    function zero() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "0"
    }

    function minimum() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "<"
    }

    function maximum() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = ">"
    }

    function add() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "+"
    }

    function substract() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "-"
    }

    function multiply() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "*"
    }

    function divide() {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "/"
    }

    function calculate() {}

    function reset() {}
  </script>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="Answer" id="input">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="1" onclick="one()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="2" onclick="two()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="3" onclick="three()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add()">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="4" onclick="four()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="5" onclick="five()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="6" onclick="six()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="- " onclick="substract()">
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="7" onclick="seven">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="8" onclick="eight">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="9" onclick="nine">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="* " onclick="multiply()">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="<" onclick="minimum">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="0" onclick="zero">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value=">" onclick="maximum">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="/ " onclick="divide()">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input type="button" value="      Calculate!      " onclick="calculate()">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="C" onclick="reset()">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a little tip: look into function parameters.

Comment: You also use > sign unencoded in html attributes which might break the html rendering in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the clicked button to the answer field, you can simply use this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nud3x0u/)

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');

for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
   a[i].addEventListener('click',addthis);
}

function addthis() {
   document.getElementById('input').value = this.value;    
}
```

Please note that an **input field** has an **value** you can alter, not innerHTML

And you don't need all the inline javascript in your html, querySelectorAll does the job

```
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="Answer" id="input">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="1" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="2" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="3" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="+" >
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="4" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="5" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="6" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="- " >
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="7" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="8">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="9">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="*">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="<" >
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="0">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value=">">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="/">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input type="button" value="      Calculate!      ">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" value="C" >
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

As a sidenote, to make your code better maintainable, I'd change the id from your answer input field to something more precise, like "answer" as input might be a little confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is great, but my code is still not working, when I press a button nothing happens in "Answer" field, I have been trying W3Schools.com examples, they work, but my code doesn't after I use your solution, or the solutions Max Meijer and Buster offered.

Comment: Do you have the javascript below or above your html? You need to put it below the html and wrap it in window.onload = function () { js code here } to ensure that the DOM is loaded before js tries to find the elements @DovydasGirdvainis

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks, now to make it work as a calculator, is there any way to add text instead of overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value attribute of the input element, not the innerHTML, for example:

```
document.getElementById("input").value = "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 var one = function() {
   document.getElementById("input").value = "1"
 }
```

Comment: The button has an onclick listener calling this function.